# Convert a cell to TimeStamp w Time zone as parameter for SQL Query in Excel 2007

Tags: sql, excel

so my query has

> where date_trunc('DAY', mh.end) > ?

However when I try to put stuff like "3/31/2012  12:00:00 AM" or "2012-01-31" in the cell, it complains about it not being Timestamp with TIMEZONE format. How can I get it to accept the date? I have been trying to search but I have not found other people having this problem (my search terms might have been off).

Comment: Ok I figured it out.

I had to convert the date to Text using

=TEXT(B1,"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")

After that it works fine.

Comment: Yup, did that now. Wasn't able to do it when I found it out (something about not being able to answer myself under 8 hour time limit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. I had to convert the date to Text using `=TEXT(B1,"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")` After that it works fine